# cómo hago que un div se expanda hacia atrás con css?

Tags: css, float, grid

y baje el div de atras cuando le doy click a un input checkbox, el div vuelve hacia abajo y no hacia la izquierda, e probado con css grid, grid-area, grid-column, order, flexbox, cuadrícula con float, pero ninguna funciona

que el b mueva al a hacia abajo:

[image: cuadricula-1]

en cambio el b se va abajo:

[image: cuadricula-2]

css:

```
.gallery{
    width: 100%;
}
        
.frame{
    height: 450px;
    width: 50%;
    font: bold 400% sans-serif;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
}
        
.click:checked + .frame{
    width: 100%;
}
        
input.click{
    display: none;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="gallery">
    
    <input type="checkbox"id="click1"class="click">
    <label for="click1"class="frame"style="background:brown;">
        A
    </label>
    
    <input type="checkbox"id="click2"class="click">
    <label for="click2"class="frame"style="background:green;">
        B
    </label>
    
    <input type="checkbox"id="click3"class="click">
    <label for="click3"class="frame"style="background:green;">
        C
    </label>
    
    <input type="checkbox"id="click4"class="click">
    <label for="click4"class="frame"style="background:brown;">
        D
    </label>
    
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Que opinas de usar JavaScript?

Comment: Daniel Briceño está bien

Comment: si con js es mucho mas sencillo ya que lo que buscas hacer es una especie de animacion cando realizas una accion lo recomendable es js

Comment: Critical Ghost cual código js recomiendas? haz hecho algo parecido?